# Bulk Update data in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am creating a Notification apps by Django Rest Framework which users can **MARK AS READ ALL notification by using PATCH API in frontend**. How can I Bulk Update data can do this task.

This serializer and viewset below just for PATCH only one notification object, but I want to do it all with Notifications which have field `is_read = False`

Edited with the right way

My Serializers:

```
class NotificationEditSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        fields = (
            'id',
            'is_read'
        )
```

My Viewset:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
class NotificationListAPIView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Notification.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = NotificationEditSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

    @list_route(methods=['PATCH'])
    def read_all(self, request):
        qs = Notification.objects.filter(is_read=False)
        qs.update(is_read=True)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My URL:

```
from rest_framework import routers
router.register(r'notifications/read_all', NotificationListAPIView)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use `list_route` for example:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import list_route

class NotificationListAPIView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    #YOUR PARAMS HERE

    @list_route()
    def read_all(self, request):
        qs = Notification.objects.filter(is_read=False)
        qs.update(is_read=True)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

the api is available by `^YOUCURRENTURL/read_all/$` more details [marking-extra-actions-for-routing](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

**NOTE!** since [DRF 3.10](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.8-announcement/#deprecations) `@list_route()` decorator was removed, you should use `@action(detail=False)` instead, I used `@action(detail=False, methods=['PATCH'])` to bulk patch, for example Thank you [@PolYarBear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9717388/polyarbear)

Comment: It got this error: Expected view NotificationEditAPIView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "id". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

Comment: This is my new URL conf: url(r'^read_all/$', NotificationEditAPIView.as_view(), name='list'),

Comment: you don't need to change url config, just go by old way to list with prefix

Comment: url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/mark_as_read/$', NotificationEditAPIView.as_view(), name='list') just for one object but I want to update all objects, Brown.

Comment: I use Nested (RetrieveUpdateAPIView) so I'm confused :(

Comment: show your current url for name='list' and code for view put to the question

Comment: return all back and just show code of your `NotificationListAPIView`

Comment: change it, bro!!

Comment: why you use for list `RetrieveUpdateAPIView` why (for example) not `ReadOnlyModelViewSet`

Comment: Updated and Error, @Bear Brown. I propose ReadOnlyModelViewSet not have method PATCH

Comment: Error: 'NotificationListAPIView' object has no attribute 'get_serializer' with your code

Comment: i can't reproduce your bug, on my system correct work with `patch` and have no error: has no attribute 'get_serializer'

Comment: Please review my code I updated. Error: Method PATCH is not allowed if use ReadOnlyModelViewSet

Comment: looks ok, but i think if you have the error, try to remove the arg `methods` like in my example and use method `get`

Comment: I think it need more a bit try to work. Error:  
global name 'Response' is not defined

Comment: Yup. It's perfect now. Thanks you very much. Vote the best for you!

Comment: glad to help you!

Comment: NOTE! since [DRF 3.10](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.8-announcement/#deprecations) @list_route() decorator was removed, you should use @action(detail=False) instead, I used @action(detail=False, methods=['PATCH']) to bulk patch, for example